# F# tail recursive call

Tags: .net, f#, tail-recursion, tail, cil

I have this code:

```
let rec collect ( t : BCFile list ) ( acc : Set<BCFile> ) : Set<BCFile> =
    match t with
    | [] -> acc
    | hr::tl -> collect ( tl ) ( Set.union acc ( FindSourceFilesForTarget ( hr ) ) )
let s = collect (Set.toList targets) Set.empty
```

It looks like it should be tail recursive, but it is not (looking at IL). Any idea why it is not compiled to use tail recursion?

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode?  Tail calls aren't optimized unless you're in release mode.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell, the `collect` function actually is tail-recursive. The first case clearly just returns the `acc`. The second case first invokes `FindSourceFilesForTarget`, then calls `Set.union` and then returns. You could rewrite it as follows (which shows the tail-recursion more clearly):

```
| hr::tl -> 
    let sources = FindSourceFilesForTarget hr
    let acc = Set.union acc sources
    collect tl
```

Because this is just a single function calling itself, the compiler optimizes it into a loop. This is how the compiled code looks (when you use reflector to turn it to C#):

```
public static FSharpSet<int> collect(FSharpList<int> t, FSharpSet<int> acc) {
  while (true) {
    FSharpList<int> fSharpList = t;
    if (fSharpList.TailOrNull == null) break;
    // The following corresponds to the second case 
    FSharpList<int> tl = fSharpList.TailOrNull;
    int hr = fSharpList.HeadOrDefault;
    // Variables 'acc' and 't' are mutated (instead of calling the function)
    acc = SetModule.Union<int>(acc, Program.FindSourceFilesForTarget<int>(hr));
    t = tl;
  }
  return acc;
}
```

On a slightly unrelated note, you could also express this using standard library functions:

```
t |> Seq.map FindSourceFilesForTarget |> Set.unionMany
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.   

as a side question, if use unionMany, would pipeline start merging sets as soon as it gets available or waits until it collects all outputs from previous pipeline step ("Seq.map FindSourceFilesForTarget" in this case)?

the reason I was doing recursive calls is to do union on sets as they become available as they have lots of same data and there lots of iterations (100's of thousands), so I didn't want to cache all results and wanted to discard duplicates as soon as possible

Comment: When `t` is a lazy data source (`IEnumerable`) then the `unionMany` operation should read them on demand (and so `FindSourceFilesForTarget` will be also evaluated on demand). So I think that in this case, the entire data set will not be loaded into memory along the way.